# How can I add a paragraph between images?

Tags: vba, import, openfiledialog

I have been adding a range of buttons to a customUi menu in Word. One of the buttons imports one or more images form a library folder on a server, but I can't get it to put a paragraph return between each image when it adds them to the page.

```
With fd
    .InitialFileName = strFolder & "\*.png; *.jpg; *.gif"
    .ButtonName = "Insert"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True  ' Make multiple selection
    .Title = "Choose one or more pictures from the library"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewPreview

'Sets the initial file filter to number 2.
'    .FilterIndex = 2

'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
'If the user presses the action button...
If .Show = -1 Then
'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
'vrtSelectedItem is a String that contains the path of each selected item.
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
                  vrtSelectedItem _
                , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True

    Next vrtSelectedItem
```

I've tried adding a paragraph line [Selection.TypeParagraph] at various places, but it just adds the return after all of the images.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to use:

```
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
Selection.Move
```

which is possibly what you are looking for??
Add the line before `Next` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I worked out that the place I need it to go is after the 'For Each' stage. I'll try it with your suggestion.

Comment: ok, I changed the answer and I added `Selection.Move` which now I guess is ok for you. Please confirm...